# Create-React-App unable to find my images folder

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with my React web app as it cannot find my images folder. I have a Navbar component inside a nav folder inside my component folder. Just outside the component folder is the assets folder which houses my img folder.

Like so:

```
src/
  assets/
    img/
      logo.png
  components/
    nav/
      Navbar.js
```

```
 Failed to compile.


./src/components/nav/Navbar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/img/logo.png' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MXlionsfieldReact\mxlionsfieldreact\src\components\nav'
```

Here is my Navbar.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logo from './assets/img/logo.png';

class CustomNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark transparent-nav-custom fixed-top" id="navbar"><a className="navbar-brand" href="/"><img className="pb-2 logo-image" src={Logo} alt="Lionsfield brand Logo" /></a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/"><i className="fa fa-home"></i><br />Inicio <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/Quienes-Somos"> <i className="fa fa-users"></i><br />Quienes Somos</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/NuestrosClientes"> <i className="fa fa-building"></i><br />Nuestros Clientes</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/Metodologia"><i className="fa fa-line-chart"></i><br />Metodología</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/Certificaciones"><i className="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><br />Certificaciones</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a className="text-center nav-link" href="/Contacto"> <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i><br />Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>  
                        </div>
                </nav>

        )
    }

}

export default CustomNavbar
```

I am running Node version 10.15.1, NPM version 6.9.0.

Comment: What is surprising about that? Your import expects the `assets` directory to be *inside* the `nav` directory. `./` doesn't mean the root directory, it means the *current* directory.

Comment: Hello Jon. Thank you for your comment. any way to circumvent this? Because I only want to reference all my images from where they are. Any advice? Thank you. By the way, I tried different route combos like: ./asset  /asset asset etc

Comment: Import them from where they actually are?

Comment: use ```import Logo from '../../assets/img/logo.png';``` to get correct path for the assets dir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.

```
import Logo from '../../assets/img/logo.png';
```

Comment: This worked. I will accept this as the correct answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is expecting assets to be under the nav directory.

Create-React-App's webpack config is pretty flexible, and will allow

```
import Logo from 'assets/img/logo.png';
```

or

```
import Logo from '../../assets/img/logo.png';
```

Although if you were to move your components folder in the future, it'd break this import.

Check out the Create-React-App documentation for absolute imports here:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports

Comment: Note that `import Logo from 'assets/img/logo.png';` won't work by default. It needs to be manually configured in a `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `../../assets/img/logo.png` as the relative path of your logo. `.` represents the current directory while `..` represents the parent directory.

Comment: Sorry. I tried that too but I am still getting the following error: 
Failed to compile.

./src/components/nav/Navbar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../assets/img/logo.png' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MXlionsfieldReact\mxlionsfieldreact\src\components\nav'